# InvalidUseOfMatchersException : anyList() to match list of string causes exception

Tags: junit, mockito

I want to test a method which accepts list of string, makes a database call and returns list of entities.

**EmployeeServiceTest**

```
when(repository
.findByMessageTypeAndStatusAndMobileInOrderByCreatedDate("confirmed", 
"received", anyList(), new PageRequest(0, 1000)))
.thenReturn(employeeEntities);
```

It gives below exception. matching the stringList with anyList() seems to be causing exception.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
  when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
  doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
  verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

anyList() to match List of string is causing the exception. any idea why the exception is caused?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Here's one, but it doesn't reproduce the problem: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/de0f85574a118d48ddaa920b77ce84bc

Comment: This reproduces the problem: https://gist.github.com/hwanders/71aeaa40804686051ddcda4090af6aa1

Comment: @JBNizet: updated the test class. Please take a look.

Comment: A complete minimal example must be **complete**. Just as the one I posted. You can copy and paste it in your IDE, compile and and run it. If you don't post your code, we can't tell why your code doesn't work as you expect it to run. It's really as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `employeeService` does not contain a mocked `EmployeeService`.
Create it by calling

```
EmployeeService employeeService = mock(EmployeeService.class)
```

instead of instantiating the real class (do not use `new EmployeeService()` here).

Update after the question has been extended:
You are mixing how arguments are matched: the first, second and fourth parameter are plain objects but the third parameter is a matcher.
If you verify one argument with a matcher, you have to use them for every argument.
There are matchers which are not wildcards but check whether the argument is equal to a fixed value: wrap your other arguments in the `eq` matcher:

```
when(repository .findByMessageTypeAndStatusAndMobileInOrderByCreatedDate(
    eq("confirmed"),
    eq("received"),
    anyList(),
    eq(new PageRequest(0, 1000))
)).....
```

Notice you have to implement a proper `equals` method in the class `PageRequest`. Otherwise `org.mockito.Matchers.eq` cannot compare the parameters successfully.

Comment: I have updated the test class in the post. It might provide more info. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you jCoder, I have extended my answer to cover this alternative scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped. I did not know, if you use matcher for one argument, we need to use matcher for all the arguments in the method. I am relatively new to junits and mockito.